# What are the limitations of home-fabricating hardware by taking advantage of graphene only?

Tags: hardware, open-source, open-hardware

I'm really a newbie in electronics and materials science, but I was wondering about the new possibilities of circuits fabrication that come with graphene and the impact that all those things could have in the hardware libre/open source hardware movement.

Could we fabricate complex hardware like the ones in high end desktop computers at home by printing graphene on paper and perhaps using 3d printers for complemental stuff?

Comment: Graphene only as in all you can print is single atom layers of carbon? You can currently print layers of graphene on paper right now; just use a pencil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could we fabricate complex hardware like the ones in high end desktop computers at home by printing graphene on paper and perhaps using 3d printers for complemental stuff?

No. The microprocessor in a high end computer contains more than 1 billion transistors. The surface of a sheet of paper is not nearly flat enough to allow so many distinct devices to be printed on it with any forseeable technology.

Furthermore, to accurately position and interconnect so many distinct devices in an area the size of a sheet of paper requires a level of mechanical precision and accuracy that is far beyond what any forseeable home printing technology can achieve.

There are probably dozens of other limitations that I'm not thinking of. These are just the two that I am familiar enough with to say are definitively impossible with any technology accessible to the consumer.